# how to open outlook on click of email hyperlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a table in which one column is an email address.
I need to add a hyperlink to this email address, so that clicking it opens outlook with the email address in `TO:` field.

Can anyone help?

Comment: <a href="mailto:address@goes.here">Email</a>

Comment: Use a `mailto:` link instead of an `http:` link.

Comment: just type

mailto:tester@test.com

in your browser, and see whats happeing

Comment: Can you show your code how you use this `mailto:` functionality in your project.So if you do somthing wrong so we can help you out.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
 <a href="mailto:abc@abc.com?Subject=ABC&Body=Body" title="title" >Email</a>
```

Here ABC is Subject and email content is body.

Comment: I tried doing like this but i am getting an error like "Windows cannot recognize the mailing address starting with mailto "
Please help em in resolving this .

Answer (score 3):

You can just use an href similar to the following (example tester@test.com email address used):

```
<a href="mailto:tester@test.com">tester@test.com</a>
```

When the user clicks the link, their default email client will be opened.

For more advanced options such as subject lines, cc, bcc, etc, see these links: [link 1](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/) [link 2](http://www.addressmunger.com/mailto_syntax_tutorial/) [link 3](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/make_a_mailto_link/). Normally mailto is a bit of a red flag for spammers, so if this is a public website then consider a link to a form with a capcha instead.

EDIT:

Try clicking Send Mail at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto) and let us know what happens. This will indicate if the problem is with the markup or the system.

You might also want to make sure that there is a default mail program assigned for that computer. You didn't indicate OS, but if you are using Windows 8 then follow [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/choose-programs-windows-uses-default) and set Outlook as the default. Otherwise, do the equivalent for your OS.

If all else fails try re-installing Outlook.

Comment: No i am facing the same issue .can you please help me.

Comment: "Windows cannot recognize the mailing address starting with mailto" - where does this message come from? Also have you tried with different browsers / computers?

Comment: yes i am getting this message Windows cannot recognize the mailing address starting with mailto when clicked on hyperlink

Comment: See the edit of my answer - Try clicking Send Mail at that link.

Comment: I think you need to re-install outlook or any email client for that. - @veena

Comment: Also confirm that Outlook is the default mail client.

Answer (score 1):

just type

```
mailto:tester@test.com
```

in your browser, and see whats happeing

Answer (score 0):

Besides set the hyperlink href property "mailto:aaa@aa.com?Subject=...", you can also create a  form with action "aaa@aa.com".
You can add form elements with name "subject" and other email elements. 
The form data will be submit to the mail client when the form is submitted.