# Create a mailto link with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a model that has an email address.  How do I create an anchor? to allow the user to simply click on it an open Outlook?  I could create an anchor manually but then how do I include the email address?

```
<a href="mailto:" + Model.CreatorEmail >Email</a>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585331/how-to-open-outlook-on-click-of-email-hyperlink 
 and  https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/138414/How-to-open-outlook-when-clicked-on-mail-id ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem:

```
@{ var email = "mailto:" + Model.CreatorEmail;}
            <a href="@email">Email</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the @ syntax

```
<a href="mailto:@(Model.CreatorEmail)">Email</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the email address attribute to your model:

```
  [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid email address")]
```

And using a `Html.DisplayFor` in your razor view

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.EmailAddress)
```

Should render it as an a tag with

> mailto:

before it's value